# removeItemAtPath behaving unexpectedly

Tags: objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to remove a folder from the documents directory of my app with this code:

```
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *downloadFolder = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([eraseDevice isEqualToString:@"true"])
{
    if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:downloadFolder error:NULL] == YES)
        NSLog(@"downloads folder deleted");
    else
        NSLog(@"erase downloads failed");
}
```

When invoked, the console prints `downloads folder deleted` but the directory remains.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code above or how to remove the folder in question? Thanks.

-EDIT to add NSLogs of documentsPath & downloadFolder-

```
/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/6C785921-89B8-49C9-8BFC-06564B95C72C/Documents
/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/6C785921-89B8-49C9-8BFC-06564B95C72C/Documents/downloads
```

Comment: please print the documentsPath & downloadFolder & tell me the output.

Comment: removeItemAtPath its remove the file not folder.

Comment: @SmartWork accordingly to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath:error:) this method also removed directories

Comment: @tkanzakic: indeed, it should be able to remove folders as well as files.

Comment: @Robert I use it before to removed directories properly, as @Girish say `NSLog` `documentsPath` & `downloadFolder` and public the result, the error could be in there

Comment: I've edited the original post to include them.

Comment: @Robert this looks righteous to me. For debugging, I'd try adding a `fileExistsAtPath:` check immediately after the successful call to `removeItemAtPath:` If that `fileExistsAtPath:` call returns `NO`, I suspect the directory is getting re-created elsewhere before you manually inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is the directory empty? Not sure if this makes a difference but just wanted to check.
2) When you breakpoint over the `removeItemAtPath:error:` line, do you see the folder delete, or do you only check it later?

Comment: Thank you. Turns out the delete method was being called before the download method had completed. Put a conditional in and that solved it.